# Error compiling a cpp containing std::chrono Error:static constexpr unsigned fractional_width = {_S_fractional_width()};

Tags: c++, std

I'm encountering an issue while compiling the following C++ code that utilizes the `<chrono>` library:

```
#include "log.hpp"
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>

#ifdef _WIN32
#include <windows.h>
#else
#define RESET "\033[0m"
#define COLOR_BEGIN(code) "\033[38;2;" << ((code >> 16) & 0xFF) << ";" << ((code >> 8) & 0xFF) << ";" << (code & 0xFF) << "m"
#endif

namespace Monolith
{
    namespace utils
    {
        void log::print_log(std::string &&message)
        {
            if (!m_enabled) return;
            auto now = std::chrono::system_clock::now();
            std::time_t time_point = std::chrono::system_clock::to_time_t(now);
            std::tm *timeinfo = std::localtime(&time_point);
            auto milliseconds = std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(now.time_since_epoch()).count() % 1000;

#ifdef _WIN32
            HANDLE console = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, static_cast<WORD>(m_color));
#else
            std::cout << COLOR_BEGIN(m_color);
#endif
            std::cout << "[" << m_entity << "] {" << std::put_time(timeinfo, "%T") << ":" << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(3)
                      << milliseconds << "} " << message;

#ifdef _WIN32
            SetConsoleTextAttribute(console, static_cast<WORD>(0xFFFFFF));
#else
            std::cout << RESET << std::endl;
#endif
        }

        std::string format_args(const char *message, va_list args)
        {
            const size_t length = 1024;
            char *buffer = new char[length];
            vsnprintf(buffer, length, message, args);

            std::string result(buffer);

            delete[] buffer;

            return result;
        }

        log::log(std::string entity, unsigned int color) : m_entity(entity), m_color(color)
        {
        }

        void log::out(const char *message, ...)
        {
            va_list args;
            va_start(args, message);
            print_log(format_args(message, args));
            va_end(args);
        }

    } // namespace utils
} // namespace Monolith
```

This is the log.hpp

```
#pragma once
#ifndef _LOG_HPP_
#define _LOG_HPP_

#include <iostream>
#include <stdarg.h>

namespace Monolith
{
    namespace utils
    {
        class log
        {
          public:
            log(std::string entity, unsigned int color);

            void out(const char *message, ...);

          private:
            void print_log(std::string &&message);

            bool m_enabled = true;
            std::string m_entity;
            unsigned int m_color;
        };

    } // namespace utils
} // namespace Monolith

#endif // !_LOG_HPP_
```

Full error list

```
┌──(recall㉿recall)-[/home/dev/monolith_engine]
└─$ ./cmake_build.sh debug
-- The C compiler identification is Clang 14.0.6
-- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 14.0.6
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Found Vulkan: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libvulkan.so (found version "1.3.250")  missing components: glslc glslangValidator
-- Configuring done (0.6s)
-- Generating done (0.0s)
-- Build files have been written to: /home/dev/monolith_engine/build
[ 20%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/utils/log.cpp.o
[ 40%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/main.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/utils/timer.cpp.o
[ 80%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/mh_vulkan/renderer/mh_vk_renderer.cpp.o
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/utils/log.cpp:2:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: error: call to consteval function 'std::chrono::hh_mm_ss::_S_fractional_width' is not a constant expression
        static constexpr unsigned fractional_width = {_S_fractional_width()};
                                                      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: note: undefined function '_S_fractional_width' cannot be used in a constant expression
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2275:2: note: declared here
        _S_fractional_width()
        ^
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/utils/timer.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/utils/timer.hpp:5:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: error: call to consteval function 'std::chrono::hh_mm_ss::_S_fractional_width' is not a constant expression
        static constexpr unsigned fractional_width = {_S_fractional_width()};
                                                      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: note: undefined function '_S_fractional_width' cannot be used in a constant expression
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2275:2: note: declared here
        _S_fractional_width()
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/build.make:104: CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/utils/log.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/build.make:118: CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/utils/timer.cpp.o] Error 1
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/mh_vulkan/renderer/mh_vk_renderer.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/mh_vulkan/renderer/mh_vk_renderer.hpp:6:
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/mh_vulkan/renderer/../../core.hpp:31:
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/mh_vulkan/renderer/../../utils/benchmark_timer.hpp:8:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: error: call to consteval function 'std::chrono::hh_mm_ss::_S_fractional_width' is not a constant expression
        static constexpr unsigned fractional_width = {_S_fractional_width()};
                                                      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: note: undefined function '_S_fractional_width' cannot be used in a constant expression
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2275:2: note: declared here
        _S_fractional_width()
        ^
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/main.cpp:1:
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/core.hpp:31:
In file included from /home/dev/monolith_engine/src/utils/benchmark_timer.hpp:8:
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: error: call to consteval function 'std::chrono::hh_mm_ss::_S_fractional_width' is not a constant expression
        static constexpr unsigned fractional_width = {_S_fractional_width()};
                                                      ^
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: note: undefined function '_S_fractional_width' cannot be used in a constant expression
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2275:2: note: declared here
        _S_fractional_width()
        ^
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/build.make:90: CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/mh_vulkan/renderer/mh_vk_renderer.cpp.o] Error 1
1 error generated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/build.make:76: CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/src/main.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:83: CMakeFiles/monolith.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:91: all] Error 2
```

The project is built using CMake with `clang` (`clang++`) as the compiler. However, I'm encountering an error within the `<chrono>` library:

```
/usr/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/13/../../../../include/c++/13/chrono:2320:48: error: call to consteval function 'std::chrono::hh_mm_ss::_S_fractional_width' is not a constant expression
        static constexpr unsigned fractional_width = {_S_fractional_width()};
                                                      ^
```

I have attempted using both the GNU compiler and the Clang compiler, and I even removed GCC and G++ after an `apt update` and `apt upgrade`. However, the error still persists.

Can anyone provide insights into why this error is occurring and how it can be resolved? I appreciate any assistance or guidance.

Comment: Please read about the [mcve].

Comment: It happens with any file containing the library 'chrono', im using linux and 2 hours ago runned an sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && reboot after what the project on which im currently working wont compile anymore,

Comment: Provide `log.hpp` so we could reproduce issue. Or at least copy paste whole error log starting from first line.

Comment: Can't reproduce: https://godbolt.org/z/on8EYaYKq most probably some local system issue. I would recommend reinstall compiler.

Comment: @MarekR indeed i can try to reinstall clang, since gnu is deleted

Comment: @MarekR after reinstalling the compiler i recieve same errors

Comment: Seems that clang is trying to include headers from GNU’s libstdc++, not LLVM libc++

Comment: @ÖöTiib how do itell clang to use its own libraries?

Comment: `-stdlib=libc++`, but this is not source of issues.

Comment: @MarekR from what i seen its a gcc/libstc++13 problem 
https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1918839.html

Comment: @HowardHinnant yes it is, since clang was using the system default c/c++ libraries, reading docs online i  saw that there is an incompatibility with gcc and libstdc++13, forcing clang using its own libs/includes fixes the problem but for gnu it may remain

Answer (score 4):

Updating the `CMakeList.txt` to use `-stdlib=libc++` and `-std=c++20` fixed it

This is the `CMakeList.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

set(PROJECT_NAME monolith)

project(${PROJECT_NAME})

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 20)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS OFF)

set(CMAKE_C_COMPILER "clang")
set(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER "clang++")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -stdlib=libc++ -std=c++20")

set(SOURCE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
set(INCLUDE_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/src)

if(CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE STREQUAL "Debug")
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/debug)
else()
    set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/release)
endif()

file(GLOB_RECURSE SOURCE_FILES
    ${SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp
)

file(GLOB_RECURSE HEADER_FILES
    ${INCLUDE_DIR}/*.hpp
)

find_package(Vulkan REQUIRED)
find_package(glfw3 REQUIRED)
find_package(glm REQUIRED)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME} ${SOURCE_FILES} ${HEADER_FILES})

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE Vulkan::Vulkan glfw glm::glm)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this (and your comments below the question) helped me turn a red X back to a green ✓ in a GitHub Action...